# Using Dashes for urls in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a view folder product_types. The name of the controller file is product_types_controller and the class I have is ProductTypesController. I'd normally keep the _ format that rails prefers but I need to keep the current page syntax for search index reasons.

How do I get this controller to show up for mysite.com/product-types and all pages in the folder product_types to appear for mysite.com/product-types/some-page?  Do I need to name the pages with - or should I use the _ syntax as well and just change the routes.

This is for a Rails 2.3.8 site.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using RESTful routes, you can do this:

```
map.resources :product_types, :as => 'product-types'
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Should I name the view files using underscores or dashes so bar_of_soap or bar-of-soap.  Especially in the controller I can only def bar_of_soap not bar-of-soap so it's having trouble seeing the action.  Thoughts?

Comment: Sure, everything behind the scenes stays the same.  Folder and file names will still be underscored.  The only mention of the dashes is in the routes file.

Comment: This doesn't work on Rails 3 - you end up with a syntax error from the url helpers:

    `syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ';' or '\n'
    ...sh_for_manage_product_discount-codes_url(options = nil)`

Answer (score 6):

For Rails 3 you have to do this differently:

```
resources "product-types", :as => :product_types, :controller => :product_types
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you're using namespaces in your routes in Rails 3, you can use the following for dashes in urls:

```
namespace :product_types, :path => "product-types" do
```

Comment: I don't think it's the same as the accepted answer. This answer helped me. +1

Answer (score 1):

In rails 3 you can do:

```
resources :product_types, :path => '/product-types'
```